# Improper integral computation using complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

$$pv\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{(x^2+4)(x^2+2x+2)}dx$$

I get an answer of $-\frac{\pi}{5}$ but wolframalpha disagrees by a factor of $2$ ($-\frac{\pi}{10}$):

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integration+%28z%2F%28%28z^2%2B4%29%28z^2%2B2z%2B2%29%29%29++from+-+infinity+to+infinity

I cannot spot the error.

I get these residues:

$$Res(-1+i)=\frac{1+3i}{20}$$

$$Res(2i)=\frac{-2-i}{40}$$

which I add up and multiply by $2\pi i$.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\text{Res}(2i)={x\over (x+2i)(x^2+2x+2)}\Big{|}_{x=2i}={2i\over4i(4i-2)}={1\over4(-1+2i)}={-1-2i\over20}$$

Answer (score 0):

I thought that it might be instructive to show another way to evaluate residues is to use L'Hospital's Theorem.  We have

$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}\left(\frac{z}{(z^2+4)(z^2+2z+2)},x=2i\right)&=\lim_{z\to 2i}\left(\frac{z(z-2i)}{(z^2+4)(z^2+2z+2)}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{z\to 2i}\left(\frac{z+(z-2i)}{2z(z^2+2z+2)+(z^2+4)(2z+2)}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{z\to 2i}\left(\frac{z}{2z(z^2+2z+2)}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{4(-1+2i)}\\\\
&=\frac{-1-2i}{20}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  If you don't find it useful, then I am happy to delete it.  - Mark